# Many to many in mongodb using spring configuration(annotation preffered)

Tags: java, many-to-many, spring-data-mongodb

I'm modeling a schema. As I'm new to Mongo DB I've no idea on how to model a nosql db.
Structuring a relational type db and using mongo on top of it does not allow me to use many to many mapping.

Using Spring-data does provide support for one to many using `@DBRef` on top of the `List<?>`. But many to many is something I want.

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Kindly prefer using code to explain. Or a demo structure to illustrate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several ways to implement many-to-many in MongoDB.

I think the simplest is the following:

**Many-To-Many Relational scenario:**

[image: Many-To-Many Relational scenario]

**After de-normalization:**

[image: After de-normalization scenario]

**And your Spring Data code should look something like this:**

```
public class Category {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String category_name;

    @DbRef
    private List<Product> products_ids;

    // ... getters and setters ...

}

public class Product {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String product_name;

    @DbRef
    private List<Category> categories_ids;

    // ... getters and setters ...

}
```

Comment: Although a pivot collection shall also help store ad preserve metadata and any necessary info about the relation between the Category and Product. How come we do that?

Answer (score 19):

> @marianomdq:
>   And your Spring Data code should look something like this: ...

When I tried this out, there is no problems, what so ever, to save the entities to the database. My problem is loading them again. That seems to cause the (in this example) load of a Category to fall into an infinite loop Category -> Product -> Category -> Produ..... Until a StackOverflowException is thrown.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionObjectFactory.getInstance(DBCollectionObjectFactory.java:51) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readDocument(DBObjectCodec.java:340) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.decode(DBObjectCodec.java:136) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.decode(DBObjectCodec.java:61) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    ........
```

Complete stacktrace is super big.

**Solution**: Lazy loading of database references!

Simply set the lazy flag of the DBRef annotation to true, this will make the loading references lazy. Which means that the circular references will not all be loaded at once.

`@DBRef(lazy = true)`

The research to actually get to this solution was cumbersome. Therefore I wanted to share this information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input to this! ;)